# How to make an ordered file structure in KivyMD?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I watched a lot of tutorials and examples about Kivy and KivyMD, but there are only a few doing complex apps, and they use to pile all the code in almost one or two files.

I am trying to do it properly, but I'm having errors that I can't understand very well as I'm still a newbie on this subject.

**THE CODE**

I made an app with the following **directory structure**:

```
mytestapp
|_ screens
|  |_ screen1.py
|  |_ screen2.py
|_ src
|  |_ kv
|     |_ screen1.kv
|     |_ screen2.kv
|_ main.py
|_ mytest.kv
```

Here's the content from **main.py**:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager

from screens.screen1 import Screen1
from screens.screen2 import Screen2

import os

KV_FILES = [
    'src/kv/screen1.kv',
    'src/kv/screen2.kv',
]

class MyScreenManager(MDScreenManager):
    def load_screen_kv_files(self):
        for kv_file in KV_FILES:
            kv_path = os.path.abspath(kv_file)
            if kv_path in Builder.files:
                continue
            Builder.load_file(kv_file)

class MyTestApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = MyScreenManager()
        self.screen_manager.load_screen_kv_files()
        return self.screen_manager
```

Here's the content from **screen1.py**:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

class Screen1(MDScreen):
    pass
```

Here's the content from **screen2.py**:

```
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen

class Screen2(MDScreen):
    pass
```

And the code from the Kivy files:

Content from **mytest.kv**:

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
```

Content from **screen1.kv**

```
<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen-1'
    ... [Code which works OK individually] ...
```

Content from **screen2.kv**

```
<Screen2>:
    name: 'screen-2'
    ... [Code which works OK individually] ...
```

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem is that nothing happens when I ran the app... Screens are not loaded.

**ALTERNATIVES**

If I remove the content from **mytest.kv** and modify the method `load_screen_kv_files` this way:

```
def load_screen_kv_files(self):
    for kv_file in KV_FILES:
        kv_path = os.path.abspath(kv_file)
        if kv_path in Builder.files:
            continue
        self.add_widget(Builder.load_file(kv_file))
```

I get the error:

```
kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.
```

So if I change the `screen1.kv` and `screen2.kv` files to just replace `<Screen1>` by `MDScreen` and `<Screen2>` by `MDScreen` too, the app works.

But the problem here is that my KV content belong to an instance of MDScreen instead of an instance of Screen1 and Screen2. And in the future, I will need to use instances of Screen1 and Screen2 which will define methods called by the KV content elements.

Do you know how to manage that preserving this file structure (or improving it)?

Comment: Your `kv` files contain rules that describe how a Screen or ScreenManager should be constructed, but they do not actually build a Screen or ScreenManager. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#syntax-of-a-kv-file).

Comment: @JohnAnderson can you give me more info? Even reading your comment and that page of the documentation, I still don't understand. I thought I was creating a MDScreenManager at the line `self.screen_manager = MyScreenManager()`. And I thought that the `mytest.kv` file was creating the Screens when doing `<TimesUpScreenManager>:
    MainScreen:
    GameSettingsScreen:
    NewPlayerScreen:`

Comment: There are two issues. Your code `self.add_widget(Builder.load_file(kv_file))` is trying to add the return from `Builder.load()` to your `ScreenManager`, but the documentation says that rules of the form `<SomeWidget>` do not create instances of the widget, they only create rules. The second issue is that in your `build()` method, you load the `kv` files after creating the `ScreenManager`, that is too late. You must load the rules before you create the widgets.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Now I've understood it.